# A struct program in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm coding a struct program that stores a group of names and grades for students in several subjects. It is supposed to receive names and grades, print them, then calculates the percentages of each subject and finally calculate the total.

The scan and printing part has run correctly, but the percentages part and total didn't work correctly. What's wrong with my code? Have I done something wrong in the calculation?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student1{
  char name[20];
  int E, sc,math; 
};

int main(void) {
  int per_m, per_E,per_sc;
  int i,total=0;
  struct student1 x[2];

  for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
    printf("%d):\n", i+1);
    printf("Name:");
    scanf("%s", x[i].name);
    printf("math:");
    scanf("%d", &x[i].math);
    printf("english:");
    scanf("%d", &x[i].E);
    printf("science:");
    scanf("%d", &x[i].sc);
    printf("%s %d %d %d\n:",x[i].name,x[i].math,x[i].E,x[i].sc);
    per_m=((x[i].math)/200)*100;
    per_E=((x[i].E)/200)*100;
    per_sc=((x[i].sc)/200)*100;
    total=((x[i].math)+(x[i].E)+(x[i].sc))/600;
    printf("percentages are: %d %d %d %d\n:",per_m,per_E,per_sc,total);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please update your post with input, expected output, and actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're program is dividing `x[i].E`, `x[i].math`, etc, it is doing an integer division and truncating the result. This means that any decimal portion of your number will be lost. What you should do is either make your values a floating point number using the `float` type, or append a `.0` to your divisors (e.g. 200 or 600 in this program) to convert your integer divisors into floats. This will force C to do a floating point division instead of an integer division, and will produce the expected result.